# Symfony2 : cache:clear have no effets on updated twigs

Tags: symfony, caching, twig

After any update of a twig file, I run cache:clear but the changes are not visible : I allways have the old twig !
I tried to manually delete app/cache/dev folder, run cache:clear, run cache:warmup bu still have nothing !

The project is in prod mode, however I updates parameters.yml and set "environment: development"

Even if I run the site from app_dev.php I have no result !

Comment: It can always be a bit tricky to try and work "outside the box" with caching.  Running in production mode while setting the environment in parameters.yml is probably something to avoid at least until you gain a bit more S2 experience.  For development mode, run "app/console cache:clear --env=dev --no-debug" after changing twig templates and of course use app_dev.php.

Comment: Then you have something else going on.  Make a clean project and see how things work "out of the box".